# ‘MSHookIvar’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, theos

i am trying to get a ivar, using MSHookIvar but i get this error :    "‘MSHookIvar’ was not declared in this scope " . i tried to compile it in my iphone, and from mac, but in both say i have this error. thanks

Here is my code:

```
#import "substrate.h"


%hook SBAwayController




- (void)_unlockWithSound:(BOOL)arg1 unlockSource:(int)arg2 isAutoUnlock:(BOOL)arg3    bypassPinLock:(BOOL)arg4{

UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(21, 80, 100, 35);
[myButton setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressed)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

SBUIController *ui = MSHookIvar<id>(self, "_uiController");

[[ui window ] addSubview:myButton];

%orig(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4);

}

%end


%hook SBUIController

- (id)window{
return %orig;
}



%end
```

Answer (score 1):

i had  this same problem try using `%orig;` instead of `%orig(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4);`. Remember to let me know how it goes